# Python: Closing multiprocessing thread stops entire program

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I've been programming for a while in python but this is my first in multiprocessing.

I made a program that scrapes a local weather station for the ambient temperature using beautifulsoup4 every minute. The program also reads temperatures from several sensors and uploads everything to a Mysql database. This all works fine but on occasion (once every day) getting the data from the local weather station fails in retrieving the webpage. This causes beautifulsoup to start an infinite loop which effectively stops all functionality of the program. To combat this I tried to try my hand on multiprocessing.

I've coded a check that kills the extra thread if that is still running after 10 seconds. Here is where things go wrong, normally the beautifulsoup thread closes after 2-4 seconds when its finished. However in the case where the beautifulsoup gets stuck in its loop not only the thread is terminated but the entire program stops doing stuff altogether.

I've copied the relevant snippets of code. Please note that some vars are declared outside of the snippets, the code works with exception of the problem described above. Btw I am very much aware that there is a plethora of ways to make my code more efficient. Refining the code is something that I'll do when its working stable :) Thanks in advance for your help!

Imports:

```
...    
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

Beutifulsoup section:

```
def get_ZWS_temp_out(temp):
    try:
        if 1==1:
            response = requests.get(url)
            responsestr = str(response)
            if "200" in responsestr:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
                tb = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "elementor-element elementor-element-8245410 elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-wp-widget-live_weather_station_widget_outdoor"})
                tb2 = tb[0].findAll("div", {"class": "lws-widget-big-value"})
                string = str(tb2[0])[-10:][:4]
                stringt = string[:1]
                if stringt.isdigit() == True:
                    #print("getal ok")
                    string = string
                elif stringt == '-':
                    #print("minteken")
                    string = string
                elif stringt == '>':
                    #print("temp < 10")
                    string = string[-3:]
                temp = float(string)

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    Q.put(temp)       
    return(temp)
```

Main program:

```
 Q = Queue()
while 1 == 1:
    strings = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S")
    t = strings.split(',')
    time_numbers = [ int(x) for x in t ]
    if last_min != time_numbers[4]:
        targettemp = get_temp_target(targettemp)
        p = Process(target=get_ZWS_temp_out, name="get_ZWS_temp_out", args=(ZWS_temp_out,))
        p.start()
        i = 0
        join = True
        while i < 10:
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            if p.is_alive() and i == 10: #checks to quit early otherwise another iteration
                print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),": ZWS getter is running for too long... let's kill it...")
                # Terminate ZWS query
                p.terminate()
                i = 10
                join = False
        if join == True:
            p.join()
```

Thanks in advance for your time :)

I have to manually stop the program which gives the following output:

```
pi@Jacuzzi-pi:~ $ python3 /home/pi/Jacuzzi/thermometer.py
temperature sensors observer and saving program, updates every 3,5 seconds
2019-10-28 03:50:11 : ZWS getter is running for too long... let's kill it...
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Jacuzzi/thermometer.py", line 283, in <module>
    ZWS_temp_out = Q.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 94, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Don't use `multiprocessing` module. Use `asyncio` module for sending in requests to API.  Just a good practice

Comment: What OS are you running? Do you see any stack trace when the main program terminates.

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment. I use a Raspberry Pi with raspbian jesse.
When I terminate the program this is what I get:
`code`
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)

    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
    KeyboardInterrupt
`code`

Comment: @bigbounty, thanks for your comment, I'll give that a try as well. I did believe it was possible to use multithreading...

Comment: Before doing `p.start()` can you add `p.daemon = True`

Comment: Also, have a look into `concurrent.features` I prefer it to multiprocessing since evth is propogated through threads unlike multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your program is waiting infinitely to pull items from the queue you've created. I can't see the line in the code you've posted, but it appears in the error message:

```
ZWS_temp_out = Q.get()
```

Since the `get_ZWS_temp_out` process is the one that adds items to the queue, you need to make sure that the process is running before you call `Q.get()`. I suspect this line of code gets executed between the act of terminating the timed-out process and restarting a new process, where instead it should be called after the new process is created.

Comment: Thanks! That is a very good and logical suggestion. I've implemented it and after a couple of days I'll report on the stability.

Comment: Thanks LARS, I'm glad my solution worked for you. Would you mind please upvoting and accepting my answer so that others can benefit in the future? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Rob found out this is the updated (working) code for the main program, the others are unchanged:

```
Q = Queue()    
while 1 == 1:
    strings = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S")
    t = strings.split(',')
    time_numbers = [ int(x) for x in t ]
    if last_min != time_numbers[4]:
        targettemp = get_temp_target(targettemp)
        p = Process(target=get_ZWS_temp_out, name="get_ZWS_temp_out", args=(ZWS_temp_out,))
        p.start()
        i = 0
        completion = True
        while i < 10:
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            if p.is_alive() and i == 10: #checks to quit early otherwise another iteration
                print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),": ZWS getter is running for too long... let's kill it...")
                # Terminate ZWS query
                p.terminate()
                i = 10
                completion = False
        if completion == True:
            p.join()
            ZWS_temp_out = Q.get()
```